# Unparsed HTML shows on search result page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, search, tag-search

When you search on any of the SE network sites, with a tag (so that a description is shown); it shows the tag info content box, with the highlight-search-term `span` elements.

For eg. I searched [`[c#] IHttpFilter` on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D%20IHttpFilter); [`[controllers] mess` on [gaming.SE]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcontrollers%5D%20mess); and the results are as shown:

> [image: c# thing]

> [image: gmaing.SE]

---

Notice the `<span class='search-highlight'>` boxes around searched tag terms.

Comment: I noticed the same issue (here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/yDLj9nn)) using Firefox 61.0.1 on Ubuntu. Yesterday (10-jan-2019) I noticed it for the first time.

Comment: Meta.SO cross-site post: [Search highlight html not rendered when using advanced search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378836/4642212)

Comment: Meta.CR [cross-site post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9062/52915)

Comment: Also happening on U&L ([e.g.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blinux%5D+test))

Comment: Reproduced in both the links, along with pretty much every other tag on SO (haven't checked other sites, but it at least seems fine on meta, and weirdly in a different FF container).

Answer (score 7):

This snuck in with [the fix for a bunch of weird truncation and escaping bugs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307626/puzzled-by-various-inconsistent-escaping-behaviours) a couple of weeks back.

Given there's no particularly good reason to highlight search terms in the tag excerpts to begin with, the sensible fix here is to... Stop adding them, and sidestep the whole issue.

Nick put this fix in today, and it should be live everywhere now.