# "Edit Approved" links are showing as plain text

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, revisions-list

I was approving an edit on DIY when i noticed that the "edit approved" link was not rendering properly on any page I could find [Example](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/98865/revisions)

[image: Edit link]

It looks like the node is somehow set to text. FF 64.0.2 (and 65.0.0) draws it as a text node. Chrome 71's inspector shows it like this

[image: Chrome inspector]

Comment: Looking at the page source, I see that `<`, `>` and `"` are encoded as `&lt;` , `&gt;` and `&quot;`. That could be the problem.

Comment: The same holds for "proposed <timestamp>" links in Suggested Edits review queue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry about this - I over-encoded (we're trying to be as safe as possible everywhere) with some changes we're making on the road to .NET Core. This specific one has been reversed and all is right with the world again!

We have some more major project changes for our migration being merged in this week...hopefully this sentence is your only awareness of them :)

Comment: Just FYI, [the same thing was reported on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379564/review-queues-suggested-edits-with-bug)

Comment: @NickCraver why not fixing the same issue for the Search Page? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322139/unparsed-html-shows-on-search-result-page

Comment: @Cœur I simply hadn't seen it (different change/break) - thanks for the ping! A fix will go up next build.

Comment: A similar bug recently arose for bounty notices: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323242/broken-bounty-post-notices